# MAVEN [mvn] launched but no ouptut detected

Tags: java, maven, java-8

My issue is related to Maven 3.0.5. I have downloaded, installed and set the path on `M2_HOME` Win 7 ENV variable.

Then I launch the command `mvn` and the cursor goes to a new line but nothing happens, no logs, just nothing. I can see in processes that a new Java process is present, but nothing more.

[image: mvn command does nothing]

If I perform the same process with Maven 3.3.9 everything goes fine.
I run a JDK 8 on my system.

[image: In this case mvn works fine]

I also tried to use a JDK 6 but the issue for Maven 3.0.5 still persist. Any hints? I'm desperate :(

Comment: I don't know Maven, but this version that "works fine" doesn't looks fine at all for me.

Comment: Please, provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't know magic, to tell you what is wrong with your code without seeing it.

Comment: well the MCVE is the one I listed.

Step 1) download mvn 3.0.5

Step 2) uncompress the file

Step 3) win 7 path updated to get the bin folder of the uncompressed maven

Step 4) launch a basic mvn command from the shell.

Comment: Sorry. I was thinking that you are trying to build something using maven.

Comment: what is really the problem? Use maven 3.3.9 with JDK 8. Maven 3.0.5 and Java 6 are very old...